# Gitlab 'exists' rules do not take artifacts into consideration

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am having a problem with some Gitlab CI jobs where I specify a rule to run only if a [file exists](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesexists).

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

#Jobs
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test/
    expire_in: 1 week

unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script: dotnet vstest test/*UnitTests/bin/Release/**/*UnitTests.dll --Blame
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/*UnitTests/bin/Release/**/*UnitTests.dll

integration_tests:
  stage: test
  script: dotnet vstest test/*IntegrationTests/bin/Release/**/*IntegrationTests.dll --Blame
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/*IntegrationTests/bin/Release/**/*IntegrationTests.dll
```

I want to run `unit_tests` only when there are `*UnitTests.dll` under the bin in `test/` folder and `integration_tests` only when there are `*IntegrationTests.dll` under the bin in `test/` folder also.

The problem is that both jobs are completely ignored. In other words, Gitlab seems to be evaluating the `exists` to false **as if it was only evaluated at the beginning of the pipeline and not at the beginning of the job**, but these paths exist because they're generated in the previous stage and the artifacts are automatically available.

If I remove the `rules` the `unit_tests` will run successfully but `integration_tests` will fail because at my specific project there are no integration tests.

I've tried replacing `exists` with `changes`, same problem.

How can I achieve this conditional job execution?

---

**UPDATE 1**: I have an ugly workaround but the question remains because the `exists` seems to be evaluated at the beginning of the pipeline and not at the beginning of the job and, therefore, anything regarding artifacts is ignored.

This trick works because I always assume that if there's a `csproj` there will be a `dll` later on as the result of the build stage.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test/
    expire_in: 1 week

unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script: dotnet vstest test/*UnitTests/bin/Release/**/*UnitTests.dll --Blame
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/*UnitTests/*UnitTests.csproj

integration_tests:
  stage: test
  script: dotnet vstest test/*IntegrationTests/bin/Release/**/*IntegrationTests.dll --Blame
  rules:
    - exists:
      - test/*IntegrationTests/*IntegrationTests.csproj
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? The gitlab docs are vague on whether this is expected to work.

Answer (score 5):

At the time of writing, it appears that GitLab doesn't support the use of artifact files in rules. [This issue confirms](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215100) that it doesn't work.

My own workaround is to remove the conditional rule and instead write a wrapper script that first checks the presence of the file.

Comment: You are right, no support for artifacts and neither for variables https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/235812 . I will like to have this, for example, to define if a `terraform apply` is needed if no changes are defined after `terraform plan` (using `-detailed-exitcode`). 
It's possible on Azure DevOps Services (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069969/getting-ado-pipelines-to-skip-steps-on-terraform-plan-no-changes) and I made it also in Jenkin before.
It's a shame.