# Getting ADO pipelines to skip steps on Terraform plan no changes

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am having trouble coming up with a solution in which I would continue with an ADO Pipeline build when Terraform returns an exit code of 2. Terraform usually returns exit code 0 when changes are detected or not, but with -deteailed-exitcode attached to the plan command: no changes is exit code 0 and changes is exit code 2.

The problem I am facing is the powers that be would like the pipeline to skip the rest of the stages and report a success if there are no terraform planned changes and to continue on the pipeline if changes are detected.

```
      - script: |
        terraform plan -input=false -no-color -out=plan.tfplan -detailed-exitcode
        # on changes detected, succeed; otherwise fail
        if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then 
          exit 0
        else
          exit 1
        fi
      displayName: "Planning Terraform Changes"
      name: TerraformPlan
      condition: succeeded()
      continueOnError: true
      workingDirectory: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform/$(ENVIRONMENT_NAME)"
      env:
        TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(NONPROD_ARM_CLIENT_ID)
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(NONPROD_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(NONPROD_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
        ARM_TENANT_ID: $(NONPROD_ARM_TENANT_ID)
    - script: |
        echo "Nothing to do"
      displayName: "No changes detected"
      name: NoChanges
      condition: failed()
    - script: |
        echo "Changes detected"
      displayName: "Changes Detected"
      name: Changes
      condition: succeeded()
- stage: ...
```

With the above pipelines yaml, the "Changes Detected" script always runs.  I'm not sure if I am going about this the correct way so any input is appreciated.

Do you think taking the approach of dropping a file and using a pipeline variable would be better such as in: [Skip stage with manual approval in Azure DevOps Pipelines (YAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503762/skip-stage-with-manual-approval-in-azure-devops-pipelines-yaml)

Update:
If I remove `continueOnError: true` then the entire pipeline stops after the stage and the "No Changed Detected" is picked up. I am trying to get the pipeline to go to another stage.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is actually a set variable and then use it in conditions:

```yaml
     - script: |
        terraform plan -input=false -no-color -out=plan.tfplan -detailed-exitcode
        # on changes detected, succeed; otherwise fail
        if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then 
          echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=changedDetected]true'
        fi
      displayName: "Planning Terraform Changes"
      name: TerraformPlan
      condition: succeeded()
      continueOnError: true
      workingDirectory: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/terraform/$(ENVIRONMENT_NAME)"
      env:
        TF_IN_AUTOMATION: true
        ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(NONPROD_ARM_CLIENT_ID)
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(NONPROD_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
        ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(NONPROD_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
        ARM_TENANT_ID: $(NONPROD_ARM_TENANT_ID)
    - script: |
        echo "Nothing to do"
      displayName: "No changes detected"
      name: NoChanges
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['changedDetected'], 'true'))
    - script: |
        echo "Changes detected"
      displayName: "Changes Detected"
      name: Changes
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['changedDetected'], 'true'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can capture the output of a task into a variable, you can utilize a [custom conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#examples) on the next stages to only optionally execute.

```
steps:
- script: echo I did a thing
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ SkipSteps }}', false))
```